# Adding controls dynamically according to data type WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I need to create a childwindow that should contain the controls according to the model passed to it. For Example, If a model contains 5 properties (it can contain any number of properties), 2 of type string, 1 datetime and 2 lists, it should create 2 textboxes with labels as property name, 1 Datepicker with lable as property name, and 2 comboboxes with label as property name. Basically, controls should be created dynamically according to properties along with the Label as name of the property. I am following MVVM. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of PropertyInfos of your model and wrap them in ViewModels. Then use DataTemplates with implicit keys to generate your controls.

Step1: Get PropertyInfoViewModels

```
var vms = model.GetType().GetAllProperties.Select(p=> ViewModelFactory.Create(p));
```

Your factory should return a StringPropertyViewModel for string properties, etc.

```
abstract class PropertyViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Caption {get; set;}
   public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

Step2: DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type sys:StringPropertyViewModel}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="{Binding Caption}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Step3:
Ensure the DataTemplates are in the Resources section of your Window or can be resolved via a ResourceDictionary.

Step4:
In the window ViewModel, expose the generated PropertyViewModels

```
<Window...>
...
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ModelPropertyViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
     <!-- This might be a good place to post your DataTemplates --->
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
   </ItemsControl>

...
</Window>
```

Comment: What I have done so far is created a ViewModel that contains a list of properties along with the type and value. Now I need to plug it to View. I am not sure what control to use. I have written a TemplateSelector Class that selects the template based on the type of the property. Only thing left is what control to use to display my window.

Comment: Normally I'd use an ItemsControls with the ItemsSource set to {Binding MyListOfProperties}